# What is the difference between using ZMQ PUB with .connect() or .bind() methods?

Tags: python, sockets, bind, zeromq, pyzmq

In Python ZMQ **publisher/subscriber** sample template, the publisher uses **`.bind()`** method and the subscriber uses `.connect()` method, that connected to the bind IP address.

But we can replace `.bind()` and `.connect()` each with the other.

My question is that what is the difference between two cases that determined below?
(two scripts in these cases work fine)

The first case, as default:

**pub1.py:**

```
import zmq
import time
from datetime import datetime

def create_pub_socket():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:9002")  # notice
    return socket

def publish(pub_socket):
    message = {
        'data': 'hi my name is benyamin',
        'time': datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    }
    pub_socket.send_json(message, 0)
    return message

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket = create_pub_socket()

    while True:
        print('\n')
        print('publisher: ', publish(socket))
        time.sleep(1)
```

**sub1.py:**

```
import zmq

if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:9002")  # notice

    while True:
        data = socket.recv_json()
        print('subscriber: ', data)
        print('\n')
```

And the second case, as the modified setup, that reversed the use of the `.connect()` and `.bind()` methods:

**pub2.py:**

```
import zmq
import time
from datetime import datetime

def create_pub_socket():
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:9002")  # notice
    return socket

def publish(pub_socket):
    message = {
        'data': 'hi my name is benyamin',
        'time': datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    }
    pub_socket.send_json(message, 0)
    return message

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket = create_pub_socket()

    while True:
        print('\n')
        print('publisher: ', publish(socket))
        time.sleep(1)
```

**sub2.py:**

```
import zmq

if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
    socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:9002")  # notice

    while True:
        data = socket.recv_json()
        print('second subscriber: ', data)
        print('\n')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference here (single publisher and subscriber), but in other scenarios (multi publishers or subscribers), there is a difference depending on your policy:

1. i.e. suppose that there are two clients (*Machine1*, *Machine2*) and a *Server*.
   Each client must publish data using **`ZMQ`**, and the *Server* must subscribe that data from *Machine1* and *Machine2*:

- *Machine1* --> has a **publisher** (with `.connect(Server IP)` )
- *Machine2* --> has a **publisher** (with `.connect(Server IP)` )
- *Server* --> has a **subscriber** (with `.bind(Server IP/Self IP)`)

As you can see in the mentioned scenario we used the second case in the question.

2. Whereas, if we have two subscribers and a publisher, we must place the `.bind()` method in the publisher and place `.connect()` method in the subscribers (first case in the question).

---

[**NOTE**]:

- <sup>`.bind()` method doesn't support the `localhost` as an IP, while `.connect()` method could be connected to each IP address that defined in `.bind()` method:   [Why doesn't zeromq work on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024003/why-doesnt-zeromq-work-on-localhost)</sup>
- <sup>Here is another example of changing `.bind()` and `.connect()` locate:  [This-Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952091/zeromq-pub-socket-buffers-all-my-out-going-data-when-it-is-connecting)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

**Operational-level difference**, there is none.

**Setup perspective difference** - **`.bind()`** method **need not know** the actual addresses ( using wildcard-expansio tricks et al ), `.connect()` method **has to know** a target address to which it will start trying to `.connect()`-to.

**Transport-class / Scalable Formal Communication Pattern Archetype** - there are cases, when some order of instantiation / becoming RTO is mandatory for proper archetype service, so, yes, there are differences, when one, `.bind()` has to become RTO earlier, before any remote `.connect()` may have a chance to succeed.

**Add-on specific features available for configuring the `.bind()` side** - are the last principal set of differences, where some more recent ZeroMQ API versions 3.2+ started to add some new access-control and similar defensive options for the `.bind()`-side node, so as to help manage plethora of risks once going into public internet exposed modus operandi.

Comment: Thanks for guidance,
what's RTO means?

Comment: Sorry, jargon, RTO stands for Ready-To-Operate ( a state, when a component / process / a system has indeed become ready to start )

Comment: Thanks a lot. I achieve to two scenario for difference between these two cases, and i placed it at here as soon.